# Matlab function for finding matrix inverse with cayley hamilton theory

Tags: matrices, inverse

I want to write function in matlab that would calculate the inverse of a matrix using its trace. I know that there are other ways to calculate the inverse but I need it to be with trace. I couldn't find anything in any other sites.

Comment: Unless the matrix is 1x1 (i.e. a scalar), you cannot find an inverse of a matrix using only the matrix trace. E.g. the inverse of $M(a)=\pmatrix{1-a\\ &a}$ depends on $a$, although the trace of $M(a)$ remains constant (=1).

Comment: @user1551 This is not redhibitory if you are allowed to use trace($M^k$)

Comment: See Fadeev-Leverrier method : http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/FaddeevLeverrierMod.html

Comment: @JeanMarie Of course you can, but then you are not using only the matrix's trace. Anyway, that's a good idea. It may be helpful if you turn your comment into an answer.